# How can I set input placeholder text in component file in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm new to Angular and Typescript. I have the input with a `placeholder` below, is there a way to change the `placeholder` text from my component file?

```
<input id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City or Town">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just bind the `placeholder` attribute. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkhzrn)

```
<input id="city" class="form-control" [placeholder]="placeholder">

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  placeholder = 'Angular';
}
```

Comment: as soon as I wrap the placeholder in '[]' I get an error that says "compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'or' at column 6 in [City or Town in United States] in ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@110:24 ("Name="city"
                        class="form-control google-place-input"
                        [ERROR ->][placeholder]="City or Town in United States">
                      <div class="invalid-feedback" *n"): ng:///AppModule/RegisterComponent.html@110:24"

Comment: can you please edit the Stackblitz and show what you are trying to achieve? I tried using 'City or Town in United States' and it works fine.

Comment: my bad. I wasn't setting the placeholder = 'placeholder'